# how to hide data from the user using delete function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating rails product controller to hide the product without deleting user grid panel using Boolean values, but I'm trying so many times, it's not working. I'm just show my code..please help where i'm missing...

I'm using ruby 2.4.1, rails 5.3.2 please help me.

rails route is,

```
  post 'products/hide', to: 'products#hide'
```

products controller function is,

```
 def hide
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.hidden = true          
    flash[:notice] = 'you have successfully hide your product'
    redirect_to suppliers_index_path        
end
```

view form is,

```
   <%= link_to 'delete', product, method: :hide, data: { confirm: 
   "Are you sure hide this #{product.Product_name} ?" } %>
```

products table migration are

```
 class AddHiddenToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
    def change
      add_column :products, :hidden, :boolean, :default => false
    end
 end
```

please help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a handful of things wrong with your code.

1. The most important issue is that **you aren't saving your changes**.

   Your controller code which reads `@product.hidden = true` only assigns the value to the ruby object in memory. It *does not* save that change to the database. I believe this is the code you want in your controller action.

```
def hide
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @product.update_attribute(:hidden, true)
  flash[:notice] = 'you have successfully hide your product'
  redirect_to suppliers_index_path        
end
```

2. Your `link_to` is attempting to use a non-standard HTTP method ("hide"). I can tell that you're interpreting this as the *controller method* you want to hit, but that's not what `method:` means here. The `method:` parameter in `link_to` allows you to specify which HTTP method you want to send along with the request. [HTTP methods](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/http/http_methods) are a standard that function as "verbs" that tell the server what you want to do to the resource you're requesting. Since you're only updating one attribute on the object, [the Mozilla Foundation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PATCH) would instruct you to use the `PATCH` method for your request here.

   **NOTE: We'll be updating the route to match this in the next point.**

   ***COMMENT: Whoever named the product's "name" column `products.Product_name` needs to have a code review meeting with someone. But anyway...***

```
 <%= link_to 'delete', product, method: :patch, data: { confirm: 
   "Are you sure hide this #{product.Product_name} ?" } %>
```

3. Your routes need to be mapped to respond to a `PATCH` method request. You *could* use the format you use in your example, but most of the time you want to use "[resourceful](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default)" routes.

```
resources :products do
  member do
    patch :hide
  end
end
```

I will add that you don't *have* to use the `PATCH` method at all. You could also use `put :hide` + `method: :put` or `post :hide` + `method: :post`. They just need to match.

Comment: thank you @jonathan it's working fine..i'm save that result another line of ruby code is 
  '@product.save' method..thank you..

Answer (score 0):

The key `method` passed to `link_to` call doesn't define controller method, but HTTP method, so it should be `:post` actually. You specify controller method by setting correct path/http method. You can achieve your goal by:

```
<%= link_to 'delete', { controller: products, action: :hide, id: product }, method: :post, data: { confirm: "Your confirmation" } %>
```

But I would go a little bit further and provide correct named route, assuming you have `resources :products` somewhere in your `routes`:

```
resources :products do
  member do
    post :hide
  end
end
```

and in your view:

```
<%= link_to 'delete', [:hide, product], method: :post, data: { confirm: "Confirmation text" } %>
```